# My Xamarin Studio target platform is grayed out

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, xamarin

I've looked everywhere for a solution , even here there's a topic talking about the same thing but there's no solution that could help.
my `xamarin.froms` target platform is grayed out in `Xamarin` studio for `windows`.

target-platform_screen-shot

[image]

Also i have my android add-ins installed as specified in the next photo
[image: add-ins_screen-shot]

and yeah, my `SDK`, `JDK` and `NDK` are perfectly installed.

[image: Sdk-NDK-JDK_screen-shot]

i had worked before on `Xamarin`.forms on Visual Studio, but Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 kinda runs slow in my PC while editing `XML` and building.
android studio is kinda better and lighter, but i think `C#` is a bit faster than `java` when it comes to compiling performances.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xamarin Studio is no longer supported/maintained.

Please [download Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) for developing with Xamarin.

Comment: Why was this noted as the correct answer? The screenshots show Xamarin Studio being used on Windows, not on a Mac. This answer is irrelevent.

Comment: This is the correct answer because Xamarin Studio is no longer supported and should not be used anymore. For mac you should use Visual Studio for Mac and for Windows you should use Visual Studio. You can take a look at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/.